# INDIRECT inside SELECT QUERY

Tags: sql, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am working on a sheet for my students and I need to filter different columns depending on their answers, that sent by a google form. I will simplify the lines here:

```
=QUERY({RESP!A2:LU1000} ;"SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3,'"&INDIRECT("A10")&"' WHERE Col2 = '"& $A$1 &"' and Col3 = '"& $A$2 &"' and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(DATE.VALUE(A5);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col1 <= date '"&TEXTO(DATE.VALUE(A7);"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ")
```

Depending on the kind of student class, I need different columns to be selected. So I have noted them in diferente cells, like this:

```
A10= Col20, COl21, Col22
A11=  Col23, Col24, Col25
A12= Col26, Col27, Col28
```

Inside the first code line, where is INDIRECT, depending on the kind of answer, I would select a different cell (A10.A11,A12). I have tried and it didn't work for me. I don't know other way to solve this, I need help, if this is possible. My final idea would be to use a IFS function to combine them. Thanks for attention.

Here is a model built to show this issue. I have extracted "INDIRECT" from "select ", as I described, to this sheet work without error.

[Sheet query test](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y2Nc-TSx61LtoglcYkhf2jE0qqBWsTKbD8kbunUB794/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Ok, I edited the answer and added a sheet model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({FORMINPUT!A1:O50}; 
 "select Col1,Col2,Col3,"&INDIRECT("A21")&" 
  where Col2 = '"&A1&"' 
    and Col3 = '"&A2&"' 
    and Col1 >= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A5); "yyyy-mm-dd")&"' 
    and Col1 <= date '"&TEXT(DATEVALUE(A7); "yyyy-mm-dd")&"'"; 0)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. That's what I exactly needed.